# Adding a String and Integer to different ArrayLists in a while loop

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop

I'm stuck on an exercise where I am supposed to take a word and numbers (separated by blankspace) and then put them in an ArrayList (diffrent lists for numbers and names).

For an example if I write "Jordan 19" the name Jordan should be put in the ArrayList called "listNames" and the number 19 should be placed in the ArrayList called "listNumbers".

If the letter "q" is typed the while loop should be broken.
The problem I'm getting is when I try to fetch the name and number from the ArrayList, I only get a blank line and the number inputted. I.e the ArrayList for numbers work but not for the name.

What may be wrong?
Thanks for the help!

```
ArrayList<String> listNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> listNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Write a name and number (separate with blankspace), end with 'q'");

boolean go = true;
while (go) {
    String full = in.nextLine();
    if (in.next().equals("q")) {
        go = false;
    }
    int len = full.length();
    int blank = full.indexOf(" ");

    String nameString = full.substring(0, blank);
    String numberString = full.substring(blank + 1, len);
    int number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);

    listNames.add(nameString);
    listNumbers.add(number);
}

System.out.println(listNames.get(1));
System.out.println(listNumbers.get(1));
```

Comment: is the input format consistent? i.e. String first, then whitespace and then number?

Comment: Yes! it's always gonna be a Name, whitespace, number

Comment: Since all 6 answers fail to explain the actual issue: Your issue is `in.next()` in the `if` check. It reads the name part of every name-number-combination after the very first input. Thus the first name will be stored fine, but the others won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic should be to read in the entire input line from the scanner.  Then, do a sanity check to make sure that it has only two terms separated by whitespace.  If so, then assign the word and number to their respective arrays.

```
System.out.println("Write a name and number (separate with blankspace), end with 'q'");
while (true) {
    String full = in.nextLine();
    if ("q".equals(full)) {
        break;
    }

    String[] parts = full.split("\\s+");
    if (parts.length != 2) {
        // you could also just break here as well, but throwing an exception
        // is something you might actually do in a production code base
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of input terms; use 2 only");
    }

    listNames.add(parts[0]);
    listNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the String.split() function would be more easier to get what you want.

As you mentioned, the input is separated by a blank space. Let's say the input is 'Jordan 19', then you can use something like this:

```
String [] data = full.split(" "); //split the input by a blank space
listNames.add(data[0]); //data[0] = Jordan
listNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(data[1])); //data[1] = 19
```

This should be working if all of your input are a String then followed by a number

Answer (score 0):

You can split then input and insert the first and second members into the corresponding arrayslists. You also do not need the boolean `go`.

```
    ArrayList<String> listNames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Write a name and number (separate with blankspace), end with 'q'");

    while(true){
        String full = in.nextLine();
        if(full.equals("q")){
            break;
        }
        String[] data = full.split(" ");
        listNames.add(data[0]);
        listNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
    }
    System.out.println("Names and numbers entered:");
    for(int i = 0; i < listNames.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(listNames.get(i) + " " + listNumbers.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont make this complicated.
 enter input as "**Jordan 19**"  and remove **q** in input.

and Use `split()` of string to separate it

```
String [] inputString = full.split(" "); 
listNames.add(inputString [0]);
listNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(inputString [1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayLists start at index 0. So if you want to output the first Item in an ArrayList you have to write `System.out.println(listNames.get(0));`

Comment: You mean `System.out.println(listNames.get(0));`.

Answer (score 0):

All answers here are suggesting the same thing, and it works. One minor addition to those is,

do this: `listNumbers.add(Integer.valueOf(data[1]));`

instead of this: `listNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(data[1]));`.

`Integer.parseInt()` returns an `int`, and you are storing a list of `Integer`. The compiler is auto-boxing the result for you. You can avoid this with `Integer.valueOf()`.